# wildcard in condor transfer_output_files

Tags: condor

I get a question of condor output file: how to make condor have all the output file in my directory, without specify the name of file?
I try to do:
transfer_output_files = *.txt

but this just give me a "*.txt" in my directory...
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

HTCondor will automatically transfer everything from it's working directory back, so as long as when you create files, they are created in the current directory, they should appear in the working directory on the submit node.

If you want to move other types of files around, then you'll need to use transfer_output_remaps, given in the documentation as:

> **``` transfer_output_remaps <`` name newname ; name2 newname2 ... ''> ```**
>
> This specifies the name (and optionally path) to use when downloading output files from the completed job. Normally, output files are transferred back to the initial working directory with the same name they had in the execution directory. This gives you the option to save them with a different path or name. If you specify a relative path, the final path will be relative to the job's initial working directory.
>
> name describes an output file name produced by your job, and newname describes the file name it should be downloaded to. Multiple remaps can be specified by separating each with a semicolon. If you wish to remap file names that contain equals signs or semicolons, these special characters may be escaped with a backslash. You cannot specify directories to be remapped.*

So there is no way to specify wildcards here by the looks of things, but by the looks of things you need to just let condor transfer the output itself.

Comment: Should *everything* in your first sentence be *all files*?  It looks like subdirectories are *not* transferred back to the submit node.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility to solve this is use an archive as output, for example `AllTextFiles.zip`.
Within your execution program add a line which takes all `txt` files and adds them to the archive.

Directly from the command line it would be this:

```
 7z a  AllTextFiles.zip *.txt
```

It can be done with 7z which shouldn't be too much of a hassle. I think you can create a zip with powershell, but that is another question. In Linux it would be even easier. Some languages have built in archiving capabilities, so that is also a possibility.

In the  `.sub` file you then need the line

```
transfer_output_files = AllTextFiles.zip
```